# Using large data JSON file in Leaflet markercluster

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json, esri-leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I want to show the JSON file consisting of many points on the map using the leaflet marker cluster plugin.

My JSON file looks like:

```
[
{
    "json_featuretype" : "Output",
    "ILCE_UAVT" : 1421,
    "ILCE_ADI" : "KADIKÖY",
    "ADI" : "Marmara Veteriner Kliniği",
    "ALT_KATEGORI" : "Veteriner",
    "ADRES" : "Bahçeler Sk. No:3 FENERYOLU/KADIKÖY",
    "TELEFON" : "0216 347 49 42",
    "WEBSITESI" : null,
    "ACIL_SERVIS" : null,
    "YATAK" : 0,
    "AMBULANS" : "Yok",
    "MAHALLE" : "FENERYOLU",
    "BOYLAM" : 29.05070181700006,
    "ENLEM" : 40.979645135000055,
    "json_ogc_wkt_crs" : "GEOGCS[\"WGS84 Lat/Longs\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"World Geodetic System of 1984, GEM 10C\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
    "json_geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 29.050701817, 40.979645135 ]
    }
},
 /////too many points information
{
    "json_featuretype" : "Output",
    "ILCE_UAVT" : 1327,
    "ILCE_ADI" : "FATİH",
    "ADI" : "İstanbul Üniversitesi-Cerrahpaşa Tıp Fakültesi Kulak Burun Boğaz Ana Bilim Dalı",
    "ALT_KATEGORI" : "Poliklinik",
    "ADRES" : "İÜ Cerrahpaşa Tıp Fakültesi Yolu No: CERRAHPAŞA/FATİH",
    "TELEFON" : "0212 414 23 59",
    "WEBSITESI" : "http://istanbultip.istanbul.edu.tr",
    "ACIL_SERVIS" : "Var",
    "YATAK" : 60,
    "AMBULANS" : null,
    "MAHALLE" : "CERRAHPAŞA",
    "BOYLAM" : 28.94229438600007,
    "ENLEM" : 41.00354611200004,
    "json_ogc_wkt_crs" : "GEOGCS[\"WGS84 Lat/Longs\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"World Geodetic System of 1984, GEM 10C\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
    "json_geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 28.942294386, 41.003546112 ]
    }
}]
```

Can I do this demonstration with the leaflet marker cluster with this json file?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a homework question showing little or no research effort. I'm deferring to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is simple.

You just need tobound your whole file in the JavaScript code and attach it to your map.

It has been explained here:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/excel-spreadsheet-batch-data-geocoding-for-geojson-and-json-files/

If I would bring your example here it could look like this:

```
   var file = {  your JSON data }
```

Next save this file as the .js file and attach it to your main map page

Then you should have all of them populated on the map as below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you accept the answer is everything is alright. Thank you in advance